# How to calculate the mean of prefix rows and make it as the new columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data format:

```
  col_a col_b
0   10   12
1   11   14
2   14   15
3   15   16
...
```

And I would like to be the following format: (2 prefix data as the mean result in each column)

```
  col_a col_b  mean_col_a  mean_col_b
0   10   12       NAN          NAN
1   11   14       NAN          NAN
2   24   15       10.5         13
3   15   16       19.5         14.5
...
```

Comment: What you are looking for is called a rolling mean : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) in tandem with [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

```
df.join(df.rolling(2).mean(), rsuffix='_mean')

   col_a  col_b  col_a_mean  col_b_mean
0     10     12         NaN         NaN
1     11     14        10.5        13.0
2     14     15        12.5        14.5
3     15     16        14.5        15.5
```